# How can I run some code when the scene changes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Not sure how well I can explain this. I have a a do not destroy on load script, so it can be moved between two scenes. However, in one scene (the one it's originally created) I need it to run the start function every time it re-enters this scene, as it draws out some of my UI. Here is the code for reference:

I could try to put it into a new script, but I am worried that since I only work on this project a few hours a week, there will be bits of code I forget to adapt for this change, and it will no longer work. How can I re-call the start function, or do something similar?

```
int spriteIndex = 0;
    foreach (Sprite texture in spriteImages) {

        GameObject button = Instantiate (shopButtonPrefab) as GameObject;
        Image buttonImage = button.GetComponent<Image> ();
        Image[] images = button.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>();

        int newIndex = spriteIndex;
        button.GetComponent<Button> ().onClick.AddListener (() => ChangePlayerSkin (newIndex));
        spriteIndex++;
        foreach (Image image in images) {

            if (image != buttonImage) {
                //button.GetComponentInChildren<Image>().sprite = texture;
                //button.transform.SetParent (shopButtonContrainer.transform, false);
                image.sprite = texture;


                break;
            }
            button.transform.SetParent (shopButtonContrainer.transform, false);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hello Mattattack. You have a script on object on which `DontDestroyOnLoad` was called, and you want to call it's `Start` method on every scene load, am I right?

Comment: Use another script that's present only in that scene to invoke a method (don't use `Start()`, rename it, but keep the contents, otherwise it'll get called twice that first time).

Comment: @trollingchar correct, but only for one scene.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of doing it in `Start` you can add a listener for [SceneManager.sceneLoaded](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html)

For doing the stuff only if the initial scene is loaded you can use [`SceneManager.GetActiveScene()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene.html) to store and later compare the initial scene to the loaded scene.

```
// Store the scene that should trigger start
private Scene scene;

private void Awake()
{
    // It is save to remove listeners even if they
    // didn't exist so far.
    // This makes sure it is added only once
    SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnsceneLoaded;

    // Add the listener to be called when a scene is loaded
    SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;

    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

    // Store the creating scene as the scene to trigger start
    scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
}

private void OnDestroy()
{
    // Always clean up your listeners when not needed anymore
    SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
}

// Listener for sceneLoaded
private void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
{
    // return if not the start calling scene
    if(!string.Equals(scene.path, this.scene.path) return;

    Debug.Log("Re-Initializing", this);
    // do your "Start" stuff here
}
```

Afaik / How I understand the example in the link `OnSceneLoaded` will also be called in the first scene as long a you add the callback before `Start` (so in `Awake` or `OnEnable`).

---

Note I used the [Scene.path](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene-path.html)s instead of `scene.name` because the `path` is **always unique** (due to the OS filesystem) while the `name` might not be.

Comment: Won't this happen everytime a new scene is loaded? Not just for a specific scene?

Comment: I guess you just add an if and check the scene? Anyway, when I've tried to implement this, it only works the first time I start the game, however, with a debug.log I can see the method works every scene change? Why would it not redraw the UI?

Comment: I overread that you want it only in one scene. I updated the answer.

Comment: Basically, I'm just creating a range of buttons, and packing them to a frame. Thanks for your help, this is looking promising!

Comment: You're welcome :) Hm so can you check if you see the log correctly? As far as I understand those buttons are not Instantiated the second time? Or is it possible they are just invisible (something is inactive/destroyed/disabled)?

Comment: If I put a log above the IF, it will show every scene I enter, but and log after the IF never seems to show.

Comment: Oh ok than it was maybe my fault. I simply assumed that the scene reference is the same but it might not be ... So better just compare the paths instead

Comment: Seems to be working great now, just getting a different error my my behalf I'll have a go at fixing!

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Add a delegate to this **to get notifications when a Scene has unloaded**.

Rather than being called directly this script code shows the use of a delegate. This means the **sceneUnloaded** value is added into a list of delegates.

In the script example below a method call is shown. Specifically, a function called OnSceneUnloaded is added to sceneUnloaded. SceneUnloaded is called when the Scene it is associated with is closed. At this point, SceneUnloaded should be removed from the sceneUnloaded list.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneLoaded1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Start()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneUnloaded += OnSceneUnloaded;
        Debug.Log("Start: SceneLoaded1");
    }

    private void OnSceneUnloaded(Scene current)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnSceneUnloaded: " + current);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("space"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Quitting Scene1");
            ChangeScene();
        }
    }

    void ChangeScene()
    {
        Debug.Log("Changing to Scene2");

        SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene2");
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        Debug.Log("OnDestroy");
    }
}
```

**SceneLoaded2** simply announces that this is the active Scene.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SceneLoaded2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("SceneLoaded2");
    }
}
```

**Resource:** [the official Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneUnloaded.html).