# "TapToPlace" script (Holotoolkit assets) do not work another scene in Unity. Is there any solution to work?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I am using Holotoolkit assets for Hololens project. In project, I use "TapToPlace" script to move object in scene. Normally it works fine, but when I open another scene and back to the MainScene, script doesn't work. How can I fix this ? (Code link https://www.paste.org/96691)

```c#
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License. See LICENSE in the project root for license information.

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using HoloToolkit.Unity.InputModule;

namespace HoloToolkit.Unity.SpatialMapping
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The TapToPlace class is a basic way to enable users to move objects 
    /// and place them on real world surfaces.
    /// Put this script on the object you want to be able to move. 
    /// Users will be able to tap objects, gaze elsewhere, and perform the tap gesture again to place.
    /// This script is used in conjunction with GazeManager, WorldAnchorManager, and SpatialMappingManager.
    /// </summary>
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Collider))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Interpolator))]
    public class TapToPlace : MonoBehaviour, IInputClickHandler
    {
        [Tooltip("Distance from camera to keep the object while placing it.")]
        public float DefaultGazeDistance = 2.0f;

        [Tooltip("Place parent on tap instead of current game object.")]
        public bool PlaceParentOnTap;

        [Tooltip("Specify the parent game object to be moved on tap, if the immediate parent is not desired.")]
        public GameObject ParentGameObjectToPlace;

        /// <summary>
        /// Keeps track of if the user is moving the object or not.
        /// Setting this to true will enable the user to move and place the object in the scene.
        /// Useful when you want to place an object immediately.
        /// </summary>
        [Tooltip("Setting this to true will enable the user to move and place the object in the scene without needing to tap on the object. Useful when you want to place an object immediately.")]
        public bool IsBeingPlaced=false;

        [Tooltip("Setting this to true will allow this behavior to control the DrawMesh property on the spatial mapping.")]
        public bool AllowMeshVisualizationControl = true;

        [Tooltip("Should the center of the Collider be used instead of the gameObjects world transform.")]
        public bool UseColliderCenter;

        private Interpolator interpolator;

        /// <summary>
        /// The default ignore raycast layer built into unity.
        /// </summary>
        private const int IgnoreRaycastLayer = 2;

        private Dictionary<GameObject, int> layerCache = new Dictionary<GameObject, int>();
        private Vector3 PlacementPosOffset;

        protected virtual void Start()
        {
            if (PlaceParentOnTap)
            {
                ParentGameObjectToPlace = GetParentToPlace();
                PlaceParentOnTap = ParentGameObjectToPlace != null;
            }

            interpolator = EnsureInterpolator();

            if (IsBeingPlaced)
            {
                StartPlacing();
            }
            else // If we are not starting out with actively placing the object, give it a World Anchor
            {
                AttachWorldAnchor();
            }
        }

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            Bounds bounds = transform.GetColliderBounds();
            PlacementPosOffset = transform.position - bounds.center;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the predefined GameObject or the immediate parent when it exists
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private GameObject GetParentToPlace()
        {
            if (ParentGameObjectToPlace)
            {
                return ParentGameObjectToPlace;
            }

            return gameObject.transform.parent ? gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject : null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ensures an interpolator on either the parent or on the GameObject itself and returns it.
        /// </summary>
        private Interpolator EnsureInterpolator()
        {
            var interpolatorHolder = PlaceParentOnTap ? ParentGameObjectToPlace : gameObject;
            return interpolatorHolder.EnsureComponent<Interpolator>();
        }

        protected virtual void Update()
        {
            if (!IsBeingPlaced) { return; }
            Transform cameraTransform = CameraCache.Main.transform;

            Vector3 placementPosition = GetPlacementPosition(cameraTransform.position, cameraTransform.forward, DefaultGazeDistance);

            if (UseColliderCenter)
            {
                placementPosition += PlacementPosOffset;
            }

            // Here is where you might consider adding intelligence
            // to how the object is placed.  For example, consider
            // placing based on the bottom of the object's
            // collider so it sits properly on surfaces.
            if (PlaceParentOnTap)
            {
                placementPosition = ParentGameObjectToPlace.transform.position + (placementPosition - gameObject.transform.position);
            }

            // update the placement to match the user's gaze.
            interpolator.SetTargetPosition(placementPosition);

            // Rotate this object to face the user.
            interpolator.SetTargetRotation(Quaternion.Euler(0, cameraTransform.localEulerAngles.y, 0));
        }

        public virtual void OnInputClicked(InputClickedEventData eventData)
        {
            // On each tap gesture, toggle whether the user is in placing mode.
            IsBeingPlaced = !IsBeingPlaced;
            HandlePlacement();
            eventData.Use();
        }

        private void HandlePlacement()
        {
            if (IsBeingPlaced)
            {
                StartPlacing();
            }
            else
            {
                StopPlacing();
            }
        }

        private void StartPlacing()
        {
            var layerCacheTarget = PlaceParentOnTap ? ParentGameObjectToPlace : gameObject;
            layerCacheTarget.SetLayerRecursively(IgnoreRaycastLayer, out layerCache);
            InputManager.Instance.PushModalInputHandler(gameObject);

            ToggleSpatialMesh();
            RemoveWorldAnchor();
        }

        private void StopPlacing()
        {
            var layerCacheTarget = PlaceParentOnTap ? ParentGameObjectToPlace : gameObject;
            layerCacheTarget.ApplyLayerCacheRecursively(layerCache);
            InputManager.Instance.PopModalInputHandler();

            ToggleSpatialMesh();
            AttachWorldAnchor();
        }

        private void AttachWorldAnchor()
        {
            if (WorldAnchorManager.Instance != null)
            {
                // Add world anchor when object placement is done.
                WorldAnchorManager.Instance.AttachAnchor(PlaceParentOnTap ? ParentGameObjectToPlace : gameObject);
            }
        }

        private void RemoveWorldAnchor()
        {
            if (WorldAnchorManager.Instance != null)
            {
                //Removes existing world anchor if any exist.
                WorldAnchorManager.Instance.RemoveAnchor(PlaceParentOnTap ? ParentGameObjectToPlace : gameObject);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// If the user is in placing mode, display the spatial mapping mesh.
        /// </summary>
        private void ToggleSpatialMesh()
        {
            if (SpatialMappingManager.Instance != null && AllowMeshVisualizationControl)
            {
                SpatialMappingManager.Instance.DrawVisualMeshes = IsBeingPlaced;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// If we're using the spatial mapping, check to see if we got a hit, else use the gaze position.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Placement position in front of the user</returns>
        private static Vector3 GetPlacementPosition(Vector3 headPosition, Vector3 gazeDirection, float defaultGazeDistance)
        {
            RaycastHit hitInfo;
            if (SpatialMappingRaycast(headPosition, gazeDirection, out hitInfo))
            {
                return hitInfo.point;
            }
            return GetGazePlacementPosition(headPosition, gazeDirection, defaultGazeDistance);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Does a raycast on the spatial mapping layer to try to find a hit.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="origin">Origin of the raycast</param>
        /// <param name="direction">Direction of the raycast</param>
        /// <param name="spatialMapHit">Result of the raycast when a hit occurred</param>
        /// <returns>Whether it found a hit or not</returns>
        private static bool SpatialMappingRaycast(Vector3 origin, Vector3 direction, out RaycastHit spatialMapHit)
        {
            if (SpatialMappingManager.Instance != null)
            {
                RaycastHit hitInfo;
                if (Physics.Raycast(origin, direction, out hitInfo, 30.0f, SpatialMappingManager.Instance.LayerMask))
                {
                    spatialMapHit = hitInfo;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            spatialMapHit = new RaycastHit();
            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get placement position either from GazeManager hit or in front of the user as backup
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="headPosition">Position of the users head</param>
        /// <param name="gazeDirection">Gaze direction of the user</param>
        /// <param name="defaultGazeDistance">Default placement distance in front of the user</param>
        /// <returns>Placement position in front of the user</returns>
        private static Vector3 GetGazePlacementPosition(Vector3 headPosition, Vector3 gazeDirection, float defaultGazeDistance)
        {
            if (GazeManager.Instance.HitObject != null)
            {
                return GazeManager.Instance.HitPosition;
            }
            return headPosition + gazeDirection * defaultGazeDistance;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is  my SceneManager code.

```
 protected override void InputDown(GameObject obj, InputEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log(obj.name + " : InputDown");
        switch (obj.name)
        {
            case BarSceneButton:
                SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(BarScene, LoadSceneMode.Single);
                break;
            case PieSceneButton:
                SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(PieScene, LoadSceneMode.Single);
                break;
            case RadarSceneButton:
                SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(RadarScene, LoadSceneMode.Single);
                break;
            case TorusSceneButton:
                SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(TorusScene, LoadSceneMode.Single);
                break;
            case BubbleSceneButton:
                SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(BubbleScene, LoadSceneMode.Single);
                break;
            case TrendGraphSceneButton:
                SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(TrendChartScene, LoadSceneMode.Single);
                break;
            case DashBoardButton:
                SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(MainScene, LoadSceneMode.Single);
                break;
            case TwoDBarChartButton:
                SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(TwoDBarScene, LoadSceneMode.Single);
                break;
            case TwoDPieChartButton:
                SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(TwoDPieScene, LoadSceneMode.Single);
                break;
            case TwoDGraphChartButton:
                SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(TwoDGraphScene, LoadSceneMode.Single);
                break;
            case MixedChartSceneButton:
                SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(MixedChartScene,LoadSceneMode.Single);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show us a piece of your code so we can help you. thanks

Comment: You can find  code in this link https://www.paste.org/96691 . I do not change in code anything.

Comment: I added the code to your question

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Is it possible that it needs to run `Start` again in order to work? see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54077872/7111561)

Comment: My application starts with MainScene. In MainScene object that needs to move have script( TapToPlace). First open, it is working clearly but I open another scene and back to the MainScene, script does not work. I examine your answer, I will try it.

Comment: How do you switch between scenes? In `WorldAnchorManager` did you enable "persitent anchors"? And you didn't answer what exactly you mean by `script does not work` ... what exactly would you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: Normally, when I tap on the object , I can move anywhere. With LoadSceneAsync method in SceneManager class, I can open another scene then when I  reopened MainScene , I couldn't move object.

Comment: @İsmetFarukÇOLAK Can you post the SceneManager code you are using to load your scenes?  On what objects if any are you using https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html.  Did you apply the Project and Scene Settings using the Holotoolkit menu item?

Comment: Actually, I do not move GameObject scene to another scene despite they are the same object but I try with DontDestroyOnLoad method as you said.Then, the result did not change. GameObject is seen every scene, yes, but TapToPlace script does not work.

Comment: Do you have an InputManager in your scene?

Comment: @İsmetFarukÇOLAK  Have you tried putting breakpoints in the code to see if it is at least being called correctly and that all the objects in the scene exist still on the 2nd load of the scene?

Comment: Yes, I tried. The objects still existed in scene and I think the error is not about the script, it's about using TapToPlace script in all objects. Then, I tried other script that name's TwoHandManipulate in MixedRealityToolkit, it works.