# can someone help me show the correct scene level in unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

im trying to show the correct scene level in the GUI or in the title of the game but I don't know how.

can someone help me? I'm new to this staff

i tried using it:  `UI_text.text = UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;`
but i dont know where to put it or what to place with it
[there is the ui text name if someone need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTOU9.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run some code when the scene changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54066091/how-can-i-run-some-code-when-the-scene-changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can get the Scenename using `SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;`
Feel free to just store the preceding text + the scene name in one pass

```
string Scenename = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;
gameObject.GetComponent<Text>().text = "level : " + Scenename;
```

That allows for the current text in your textbox to be replaced with "level : [Scenename]"
As long as you name the Scenes accordingly, this will allow you to display the scenenames
if you want o just display the Scene ID numbers, this is all you change :

```
string Scenename = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex.ToString();
```

Hopefully this helps, Cheers!

Comment: where i need to put this code? in my levelnumber script?

Comment: You can add this directly onto the text object that updates the current level text, and yes on your levelnumber script, as long as that script is attached to the text obj itself, you will be fine!

Comment: its giving me that red line under the Scenename and `gameObject.GetComponent<Text>().text = "level : " + Scenename;`

how do i fix it? do i need to add something?

Comment: do you have 
string Scenename = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name; 
above it?

Comment: amm yes i fixed it